# Why does water randomly come out of the kitchen tap every now and then

Tags: plumbing, taps

Sometimes the taps have a little bit of water come out for a few seconds while I'm just sat around not doing anything with the sink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this happens just one or twice a few minutes after you've used the cold tap, it's more likely to be thermal expansion. Especially in the winter when the water arrives further below room temperature, or if you have a mixer tap. Some taps hold quite a lot of water, and the few percent thermal expansion from the incoming temperature to run temperature can easily account for a little bit of water coming out.

On the hot, this can't happen, as instead the water shrinks as it cools. But the tap can open slightly as it cools. This tends to make it drip repeatedly.

Comment: This happens to me for many different taps. Old and brand new so this must be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The seal in your faucet is failing, and water is building up very slowly. [Surface tension keeps it in a shallow bubble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2mKpZHnEzw) until it finally flows out the horizontal faucet segment in a burst.

Disassemble your faucet and check for mineral deposits and other debris. Clean or replace the ceramic or rubber seals, and lubricate rubber seals with white grease.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a leakage around the faucet washers, seals or cartridges. water will always come out when the pressure is high because of the leaks. Use gauge to check the pressure or call your plumber.